# Swift Program button action viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am wondering how do I get the following programmable button to action when pressed to go to another viewController.

Currently the button calls a function in the same view controller but I want it to go to SocialLoginViewController as Apple rejected my app because it does not allow Apple Signin so I need to change my app to allow that.

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Person", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.checkLogin(_:)))
rightBarButton.image = buttonIcon
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

So I am wondering what do I need to change to get the action to load

```
SocialLoginViewController
```

Comment: show the code of checkLogin

Comment: So you want you use `checkLogin(_:)` method of FirstViewController  in another class ?

Comment: well you can use NotificationCenter for that.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I want navigate to another ViewController.